# Is there any listener which callback when view is visible to user?

Tags: java, android

I have exoplayer in viewpager2. How can I play exoplayer at visible position with pageChangecallback. Where should I put pageChangecallback? In fragment or adapter? Is there any listener which triggers when view is visible to user?

```
class videosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnItemOnScreenListener
{
SimpleExoPlayer player; PlayerView playerView;
public videosHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
playerView = itemView.findViewById (R.id.videos_tab_videoView1);
}
public void Exoplayer(String video)
    {
        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
        playerView.setPlayer (player);
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        player.prepare();
        player.setPlayWhenReady (false);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view's visibility with ViewPager is quite tricky because it loads two or three fragments at once and all of them are `technically` visible to the user. once you switch to another fragment this fragment will be visible in addition to the next and last fragment.

In normal cases, we can use the `ViewTreeObserver` interface which has the `onGlobalLayout` interface that can observe the changes in the layout.

However, in your case, you have no solution but to use the `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback` callback. which will also ensure that the view is already visible as it's already been created when you switched to the previous page.

About your question regarding putting it into the fragment or the adapter, this is a view-related configuration that should be put in the fragment, not the adapter.

Comment: I am now using map to save instance of playerview with position as key. Then I can pause or play exoplayer from fragment with ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback. But what if a user watch 1000 videos? There will be a map of 1000 playerviews which will degrade the performance, right. Is there any workaround to play or pause video from fragment? If it was just one playerview I could use getter method.